# Comparing address of std::endl

Tags: c++, function-pointers, endl

I am inspecting a piece of existing code and found out it behaves differently when compiled with Visual C++ 9 and MinGW:

```
inline LogMsg& LogMsg::operator<<(std::ostream& (*p_manip)(std::ostream&) )
{
    if ( p_manip == static_cast< std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&) > ( &std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >) )
    {
        msg(m_output.str());
        m_output.str( "" );
    }
    else
    {
        (*p_manip) (m_output);            // or // output << p_manip;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

As the name suggests, this is a log class and it overloads `operator<<()` to strip endls from the stream.

I found out why it behaves differently: the test `p_manip == static_cast...` succeeds with MinGW while it fails with Visual C++ 9.

- MinGW "ignores" the cast and returns the real address of `std::endl`;
- Visual C++ 9 actually casts the pointer-to-endl and returns a different address.

I changed the test to `if ( p_manip == std::endl )` and now it behaves as expected.

**My question is**: what is the rationale behind such a complicated (and, as a matter of fact, wrong) test?

---

For the sake of completness:

```
class LogStream
{
public:
    LogStream() {}
protected:
    std::ostringstream m_output;
};

class LogMsg : public LogStream
{
    friend LogMsg& msg() ;
    static LogMsg s_stream;
public:
    LogMsg() {}
    template <typename T>
        inline LogMsg& operator<<(T p_data);
    inline LogMsg& operator<<(std::ostream& (*p_manip)(std::ostream&) );
};
```

Comment: When does your source control say that the test was written?  It may be that at that time the operator==() did not work for these types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information:

The statement `if ( p_manip == std::endl )` does not compile on the original compiler (gcc 3.4.5, the compiler on which the code was originally developed).

That means the test was not wrong as I stated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I'd say the original author didn't realise they were compatible types, and did the conversion on spec (without the compiler requiring him to).